# How can I draw a simple factor tree like this?

Tags: trees

[image]

I am trying to draw a factor tree for my elementary students like this.

What are the possible ways / packages to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The context of use the showed image is not entirely clear, so see if the following image is what you after.

[image]

The MWE, which produce it, is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
  inner sep=1pt
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {5,x,x,x}
    \node (n\j) [on chain] {$\i$};
\node (n0) [above = of $(n1)!0.5!(n4)$] {$5x^3$};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw[-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}] (n0) -- (n\i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
or draw it as tree by use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    inner sep = 1pt,
   math content,
   edge = -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
   l sep=11pt,
   s sep=1pt,
            }
[5x^3 [5][x][x][x]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , it solves my problem much efficiently

Comment: +1 Very clever code

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you very much for the compliment!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have upvoted all the users...:-)

Answer (score 5):

A simple code with  `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{array}{c}
        \rnode{C}{5x^3} \\ \\
        \rnode{F0}{5}\, \Rnode{F1}{x}\, \Rnode{F2}{x}\, \Rnode{F3}{x}
        \end{array}
        \psset{nodesep=2pt, linewidth=0.5pt, arrowinset=0.2, linejoin=1}
        \multido{\i =0+1}{4}{\ncline{->}{C}{F\i}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]